# can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'list'

Tags: python

```
def evalPolynomial(coeffs,x):
        return sum([n for n in coeffs] * [x**(m-1)for m in range(len(coeffs),0,-1)])
```

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'list'

Not sure what's causing the error?  When I print each of the statements separately, they each give me a list, but when I try to multiply them it doesn't work.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: For a list coeffs and a variable x, return the sum of the sequence a-sub(n)*x^(n) + a-sub(n-1)*x^(n-1)...a-sub(0)*x*0

Comment: It's for polynomial estimation

Comment: You might want to have a look at bumpy which allows arrays to be multiplied like that.

Answer (score 14):

Python `list` s can only be multiplied by an integer, in which case the elements of the `list` are repeated:

```
>>> [1,2,3] * 3
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

If you want vectorial operations use `numpy.ndarray` instead:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> ar = np.array([1,2,3])
>>> ar * 3
array([3, 6, 9])
```

In particular there is a numpy function for convolution(i.e. polynomial multiplication):

```
>>> a = np.array([1,2,3]) # 1 + 2x + 3x^2
>>> b = np.array([4,5,6]) # 4 + 5x + 6x^2
>>> np.convolve(a, b)     # (1 + 2x + 3x^2) * (4 + 5x + 6x^2)
array([ 4, 13, 28, 27, 18]) # 4 + 13x + 28x^2 + 27x^3 + 18x^4
```

If you want to evaluate a polynomial there is the `numpy.polyval` function which does this.

Keep in mind that using numpy limits the size of the integers, so you might obtain wrong results if the coefficients are so big that they overflow.

Comment: Python lists could be multiplied by a variable. Actually to be clear, I was trying to create a 2D lists of variable length. I have posted my 2 line snippet.
#code
def buildAdjMat(matLen):
    adjMat = [[0]*int(matLen)]*int(matLen)

Comment: @SteveJobs When I say *integer* I mean any expression whose evaluation ends in a value that is of type integer.

Comment: Helped me a lot!

Answer (score 2):

The expression `[n for n in coeffs]` is a `list`, of integers.
Lists do support multiplication by an integer, but this means "make a list that 
is n copies of the starting list"; this is not what you want in this mathematical context.

I would recommend that you look at the `numpy` (or `scipy` which is largely a superset of `numpy`) package to help with this.  It has a function [`polyval`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.poly.html) for evaluating exactly what you want, and also provides a class based representation `polynomial`.  In general, for doing numeric computation in Python, you should look at these packages.

But if you want to roll your own, you'll need to do the math inside of the list comprehension,
one way to do it is:

```
return sum( [ n*x**(i-1) for (n,i) in zip( coeffs, xrange(len(coeffs),0,-1)) ] )
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to multiple two lists together. This is not a valid operation in python.

If you want to multiply each corresponding element in the two lists you can use something like this:

```
def evalPolynomial(coeffs,x):
        return sum(x * y for x, y in zip(coeffs, (x**(m-1)for m in range(len(coeffs),0,-1))))
```